# Count number of posts in a custom post type taxonomy (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, categories

I am trying to return a list of all categories in a custom taxonomy (shoes), along with the number of posts each category has in it (the post type is 'items' if it helps to know). But my code doesn't seem to show the number of posts:

```
<ul>
<?php
$shoes = array(
        'taxonomy'      => 'shoes',
        'hide_empty'    => 0,
        'orderby'       => 'name',
        'order'         => 'ASC',
        'hierarchical'  => 0
    );
    $count_query = new WP_Query( $shoes );
    $cats = get_categories($shoes);
    foreach($cats as $cat) {
?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $cat->term_id ) ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?><span><?php echo $count_query->found_posts; ?></span></a>
    </li>
<?php
}
?>
</ul>
```

The category name and links work, but the number of posts (inside the `<span>`) always returns 1 regardless of how many posts there actually are. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try $cat->count

Comment: Solved - and so obvious. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
    <?php
    $shoes = array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'shoes',
            'hide_empty'    => 0,
            'show_count' => 1, // if add this value you can use echo $cat->count; without any queries
            'orderby'       => 'name',
            'order'         => 'ASC',
            'hierarchical'  => 0
        );
        $count_query = new WP_Query( $shoes );
        $cats = get_categories($shoes);
        foreach($cats as $cat) {
    ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $cat->term_id ) ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?><span><?php echo $cat->count; ?></span></a>
        </li>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </ul>
```